# Spring Boot, Angularjs, changing server.context-path breaks the angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, contextpath

I have a Secure Single Page Application on Spring Boot and Angularjs. 
The entry point to the ui application is http://localhost:8080/ and 
the application uses embeded Tomcat with no server.context-path in the properties file. 
Everything worked well until I did not set server.context-path in application.yml:

server:
  context-path: /appname

Then I got an error loading all .js resources on the client side. When I looked in the developer tool in browser I followed messages like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for all .js resources.

How do I set up on the server side the default path to the static resources used by the Angular application? I think that configure it on the client side is wrong way and there must be a way to do it on the Spring-Boot side.

Here is my code parts:

POM.xml

```
 <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Spring boot app runner:

```
 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.logout().and().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
```

application.yml

```
server:
  context-path: /appname

spring:
  resources:
    chain:
      enabled: true
```

In index.html imported resources as follows:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
var ticketsApp = angular.module('ticketsApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'
]).
        config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

                $routeProvider.when('/search', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/search/search.html',
                    controller: 'SearchController'
                }).when('/stat', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/stat/stat.html',
                    controller: 'StatController'
                }).when('/admin', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/admin/admin.html',
                    controller: 'AdminController'
                }).when('/details', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/search/details/details.html',
                    controller: 'DetailsController'
                }).otherwise('/search');

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using thymeleaf to process my HTML so I was able to fix this pretty easily using a combination of an angular constant and an $httpProvider interceptor.

In my index.html <head> I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  var app = {
    contextPath: /*[[@{/}]]*/
  };
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Then, prior to loading my app.js I do :

```
<script>
  angular.module("root", []).constant("$contextPath", app.contextPath);
</script>
```

Then, in my app.js, I setup an http interceptor to alter the URL.

```
angular.module('myapp', [
'root'
'ngRoute'])
  .config(['$httpProvider','$contextPath', function($httpProvider, $contextPath) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
      return {
        'request': function(config) {
          if (! config.url.startsWith($contextPath)) {
            config.url = $contextPath + config.url;
          }
          return config;
        }
      };
    });
  }]);
```

This prepends the context path on requests.  This is just an initial implementation, it needs to be more intelligent to deal with FQDNs, etc. but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem with the information in: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

And i have adapted the Trever Shick answer. I don't use thymeleaf, so i use an static contextPath

```
angular.module('myapp', [
'root'
'ngRoute'])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
      return {
        'request': function(config) {
          if (! config.url.startsWith("appName")) {
             config.url = "appName" + config.url;
          }
          return config;
        }
      };
    });
  }]);
```